# Can we prove whether the following vector operation is distributive or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

I define a vector operation as follows:
$$\vec{a}\tilde\times \vec{b}=\vec{a}.\vec{b}(\hat{\perp})=ab \cos\theta(\hat{\perp})$$
where $(\hat{\perp})$ is a unit vector perpendicular to $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ which we get by right hand rule.

Now can we prove whether this vector operation is distributive or not?

Comment: What's $\widehat\perp$ when $\overrightarrow a$ and $\overrightarrow b$ are linearly dependent? And, when they aren't, which of the two versors in $\left(\operatorname{Span}(\vec a,\vec b)\right)^\perp$ is it?

Comment: Undefined. So is this operation not a genuine operation?

Comment: And, when they aren't.....is it? What do you mean?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Right hand rule

Comment: Add it to the question. However, it is indeed not a genuine operation.

Comment: He's saying that if a and b are parallel or anti-parallel how would you define the perpendicular vector since there are an infinite number of them

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Thanks. Are there any other reason(s) which make it not a genuine operation?

Comment: No. When $\vec a\times \vec b\ne 0$, it $\vec a\tilde\times \vec b$ is indeed well defined as $$\frac{\vec a\cdot\vec b}{\sqrt{(\vec a\cdot\vec a)(\vec b\cdot\vec b)-(\vec a\cdot\vec b)^2}}\vec a\times\vec b$$ and when $\vec a=0\vee \vec b=0$ it is unambiguously $0$.